# Implementar pesquisa junto com respostas

Tags: novo-recurso, pesquisa

#### Contexto

Estava querendo pesquisar um resposta de uma de minhas perguntas já feitas.
Desta forma fui ate meu usuário e apos pesquisar pelo termo especifico, contudo o termo era da resposta e não da minha pergunta, assim o resultado não foi encontrado.

`user:14213 [sql] is:question rn`

#### Analise

1. `user:14213` meu usuário
2. `[sql]` tag envolvida
3. `is:question` é um pergunta
4. `rn` string envolvida (que esta na resposta)

#### Resultado esperado

[Sql - Merge select - Criar row caso registro inexistente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92288/sql-merge-select-criar-row-caso-registro-inexistente#answer-92315)

#### Questão

Minha analise sobre a resposta esta incorreta? se não esta, então recurso poderia ser implementado?

Comment: Onde está a string `rn`?

Comment: @JorgeB. na resposta `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd_setor ORDER BY NR_TOTAL_TICKET ASC) RN`

Comment: mas a busca funcionou, não?

Comment: @Math não, pois o RN esta na resposta.

Comment: Ainda não entendi qual é a sua solicitação de novo recurso. Se você está procurando uma resposta deve escrever `is:answer`. Se você não sabe se é em pergunta ou resposta não escreva o `is`. BTW, a pergunta não tem a tag `[sq]`. Se procurar assim: `user:14213 is:answer rn` você encontra. [Link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14213+is%3Aanswer+rn).

Comment: @Math Se entendi bem, ele quer procurar a string nas respostas de uma pergunta que ele criou. Ou seja, não a resposta dele e sim em uma resposta que ele recebeu em uma pergunta. Mas filtrando pelo usuário dele, mostrando que o filtro deve ser somente nas respostas de perguntas que ele criou.

Comment: @Math não, este resultado é para um resposta minha, note que a pergunta é minha mas a resposta que quero é do [Jean](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92288/sql-merge-select-criar-row-caso-registro-inexistente#answer-92315)

Comment: Agora entendi. Valeu aos dois!

Comment: @Randrade exatamente.

Comment: +1, pensei bem sobre a ideia e acho que quanto mais opções tivermos para uma busca avançada melhor

Comment: Aos navegantes, tem os atalhos `is:q` e `is:a`